# cshtml radiobuttons disable

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing a mvc project, I have a cshtml file which has radiobuttons for the page. When i disable one of them, the other one's position changed. it sliped little left (font decrease) How can i prevent this ? [image]

My radiobuttons:

```
<td>
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.getA, true, new {id = "9", onclick = "", data_bind = "value:getA" }) True
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.getB, false, new {id = "10", onclick = "", data_bind = "value:getB" }) False
</td>
```

Comment: Use your browser tools an check the css

Answer (score 0):

I solved this:
In my project f_disable function  load disable.png for the disabled radiobutton and create a new id. I reached attributes with this new id and I changed the disable.png width and padding in javascript.

```
document.getElementById("9_ReadOnly").style.width = "15px";


document.getElementById("10_ReadOnly").style.width = "15px";
document.getElementById("9_ReadOnly").style.paddingLeft = "3px";
 document.getElementById("10_ReadOnly").style.paddingLeft = "6px";
```

[image]